# switch notification to show

Tags: java, android, xml

Depending on the circumstance I would change the notification to show so I wrote this code.

To call it in another class use

But eclipse give me "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method ShowNot(int) from the type Notification" Why? How can i fix?

Answer (score 1):

`MostraNotifica (int Id)` is not `static`. You should do Something like

```
Notifica notifica = new Notifica(context);
notifica.MostraNotifica(Notifica.NOTIFICA);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling a non static method (`public void MostraNotifica(int Id)`) as if it were a static method.

I would instead make the class a singletong, that way you only need to initialize it once but can use the methods like you please.

Sample singleton:

```
public enum Notifica {
    INSTANCE;

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    Context context;

    public void init(Context context) {
        if (mNotificationManager == null) {
            this.context = context;
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            // Do any other initializations you need here
        }
    }

public void MostraNotifica (int Id) {

    switch(Id)
    {
    case NOTIFICA:
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text1");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Text1");
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICA, notificationBuilder.build());
        break;
    case NOTIFICA2:
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Text2");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Text2");
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICA2, notificationBuilder.build());
        break;
    }
    notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS );
}
```

You will initialize and use this singleton like this:

```
Notifica.INSTANCE.init(this);
Notifica.INSTANCE.MostraNotifica(1);
```